# Travis CI stage failed in matrix

Tags: travis-ci

I am trying to use Travis stages in a matrix but it seem that script used is the default one (`npm run test`) except for one.

Here the travis.yml

```html
if: tag IS blank

git:
  depth: 1
sudo: false

matrix:
  fast_finish: true

cache: yarn

language: node_js
node_js:
  - "node"
  - "lts/*"
env:
  - COMPONENT=@emmanuelgautier/lerna-example-hapi
  - COMPONENT=@emmanuelgautier/lerna-example-react-app
  - COMPONENT=@emmanuelgautier/lerna-example-validators
stages:
  - test
  - build
  - name: publish
    if: branch = master
jobs:
  include:
    - script: yarn bootstrap --scope=$COMPONENT && yarn lerna run --scope=$COMPONENT test:ci
    - stage: build
      script: yarn lerna --scope=$COMPONENT build
    - stage: publish
      env:
        - COMPONENT=all
      script: yarn publish
    - stage: deploy
      script: skip
```

Here an example issue : https://travis-ci.org/emmanuelgautier/lerna-example/builds/355884540

Do you think the error is from the travis file or because this feature is in beta mode ?

Comment: I forked your project on github to try on my account.
Could you tell me what you would like exactly as build matrix please? I mean, 6 tests, 6 builds, 1 publish and 1 deploy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I was not clear in my first question. My need was to expand matrix on each stage. It seem that is not possible for the moment (https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/8295).

The workaround found is the following (without matrix expansion)

```html
if: tag IS blank

sudo: false
git:
  depth: 1

matrix:
  fast_finish: true

cache: yarn

language: node_js
node_js:
  - "node"

jobs:
  include:
    - stage: test
      node_js: "node"
      env: COMPONENT=@emmanuelgautier/lerna-example-hapi
      script: ./ci/test $COMPONENT
    - stage: test
      node_js: "lts/*"
      env: COMPONENT=@emmanuelgautier/lerna-example-hapi
      script: ./ci/test $COMPONENT
    - stage: test
      node_js: "node"
      env: COMPONENT=@emmanuelgautier/lerna-example-react-app
      script: ./ci/test $COMPONENT
    - stage: test
      node_js: "lts/*"
      env: COMPONENT=@emmanuelgautier/lerna-example-react-app
      script: ./ci/test $COMPONENT
    - stage: test
      node_js: "node"
      env: COMPONENT=@emmanuelgautier/lerna-example-validators
      script: ./ci/test $COMPONENT
    - stage: test
      node_js: "lts/*"
      env: COMPONENT=@emmanuelgautier/lerna-example-validators
      script: ./ci/test $COMPONENT
    - stage: build
      node_js: "node"
      env: COMPONENT=@emmanuelgautier/lerna-example-hapi
      script: ./ci/build $COMPONENT
    - stage: build
      node_js: "lts/*"
      env: COMPONENT=@emmanuelgautier/lerna-example-hapi
      script: ./ci/build $COMPONENT
    - stage: build
      node_js: "node"
      env: COMPONENT=@emmanuelgautier/lerna-example-react-app
      script: ./ci/build $COMPONENT
    - stage: build
      node_js: "lts/*"
      env: COMPONENT=@emmanuelgautier/lerna-example-react-app
      script: ./ci/build $COMPONENT
    - stage: build
      node_js: "node"
      env: COMPONENT=@emmanuelgautier/lerna-example-validators
      script: ./ci/build $COMPONENT
    - stage: build
      node_js: "lts/*"
      env: COMPONENT=@emmanuelgautier/lerna-example-validators
      script: ./ci/build $COMPONENT
    - stage: publish
      script: skip
    - stage: deploy
      script: skip

stages:
  - test
  - build
  - name: publish
    if: branch = master
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `script` is not defined on the top level, the default is used in the jobs that do not have it explicitly defined (the 6 jobs using `node` and `lts/*`—and 3 `env` vars—in the `test` stage). If you need a custom `script`, add one at the top level.